# broadcast receiver inside activity

Tags: android, service

Hi folks how I can implement a Broadcast receiver in an activity that receives intent from a service along with some parameter's of int and string type?

**UPDATE:**

I have this under the Activity:

```
 private BroadcastReceiver ReceivefrmSERVICE = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "IN DA BroadCASTER",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

   };
```

and I have this under a function in the service that is called on a event from another activity when a checked button is checked:

```
 public void switchSpeaker(int hr, int min){

       Toast.makeText(Server.this, hr +" , " +min, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       Intent intent = new Intent(this, andRHOME.class);
       //intent.putExtra("sendMessage","1");
        startActivity(intent);
        /*PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(Server.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager almmgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
        int min1 = cldr.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        cldr.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cldr.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
        almmgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cldr.getTimeInMillis(), pi);*/
    }
```

But its crashing?? ,What to do?

Comment: basically, the two pieces of code you pasted aren't related to each other and don't form a logical communication. you need to decide if you want to make an intent and startActivity(intent), in this case you need to implement onCreate and onNewIntent in the activity to deal with the intent information. 
OR you want to use the broadcasting system and then send the intent with sendBroadcast(intent);

Comment: Take a look in this link on how he is sending a broadcast intent:
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/

An if it's crashing, please add the exception at least.

Comment: I used sendBroadcast in place of the wrong startActivity() now there is no exception NO crashing But now I will check whether the thing is working as wanted! as actually I wanted to pass a variable and then use a function embedded under Activity! **Update** in the broadcaster receiver the Toast isn't running so it means the Broadcast isn't being received, Am I Correct?

Comment: did you register the receiver with the registerReceiver function? see my original answer.
Are you sure your activity is existing at all? (see my first comment)

Comment: Sorry left that but here I should put Intentfilter >> IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
 just below the receiver?  **Another thing**  I'm not sure what I have to pass as a parameter in .addAction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         
       // DO YOUR STUFF
    }
}

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
```

in onResume: (so you receive only while in foreground)

```
filter.addAction(/* the action you want to receive */);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

in onPause: (the try catch is to fix a bug in unregister in case it is called twice)

```
try {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    if (e.getMessage().contains("Receiver not registered")) {
        // Ignore this exception. This is exactly what is desired
        Log.w(TAG,"Tried to unregister the reciver when it's not registered");
    } else {
        // unexpected, re-throw
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the service is yours and you want also to make sure the activity is actually active, it's probably better to start your activity from the service with the intent and in the activity you should handle onNewIntent event to take care of the situation where your activity is already active.

Comment: Actually I will not have the activity active but still want to use its function ? is this possible if I do only onReceive() ?

Comment: So your question is in the wrong direction, what you should do is write a class extending BradcastReciver and register it in your app manifest. so it handles the action.

Comment: If the activity isn't in foreground then android might kill it at any point and you have no way to make sure your receiver will be called at all. You can offcourse register in onCreate and unregister in onDestroy

Comment: But the problem is that If I form a separate class with BroadcastRec. extending it then I will not have that function accessible that is actually under a activity.

Comment: As I wrote you can register on onCreate and unregister in onDestroy but Activities aren't meant to run in background for a long time, that's what you have a service for.

Comment: can you show some way to register sorry for this but i need and I just need to access that function temporary at the time of making function call from service so I think that I do do not need to care for activity running for long time or not!

Comment: I'm not so clear on the situation, and you didn't give enough details in your question. the code that I already gave in my answer allows you to register and unregister the receiver in runtime, where you put it is your decision.

Comment: So you mean I should instantiate the Broadcaster in onCreateunder this is >> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) in my acitivity right now Im instantiating Broadcaster straight under acitvity!

Comment: Raanan ,Please see above under UPDATE about what is happening now!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class myActivity extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        }
    };
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


}
```