# addAction() & Service calling Dilemma

Tags: android

I'm stuck here at my previous struggle >> [Prev. Struggle!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880004/broadcast-receiver-inside-activity)

Raanan there helped! me a lot but then he I think went away as timing zone is different , now I'm stuck with my service code that I'm using to call my BroadcastReceiver() that is in the activity! and also I'm not getting with what parameter I should load the filter.addAction(action); in place of action??

Kinldy guide me!

CODE in the Server:

```
Toast.makeText(Server.this, hr +" , " +min, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       Intent intent = new Intent(this, andRHOME.class);
       //intent.putExtra("sendMessage","1");
       sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and CODE IN THE ACITIVITY(Broadcast Receiver)

```
 private BroadcastReceiver ReceivefrmSERVICE = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "IN DA BroadCASTER",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                sendMessage("1");
    }
   };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add these line to regiester your receiver for some action for example define a Global variable like this:

```
public static String NOTIFCATION_BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.your_packagename.UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_INTENT";
```

then register the action like this in your `activity onCreate()` Method.

```
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
 filter.addAction(Global.NOTIFCATION_BROADCAST_ACTION);
 registerReceiver(ReceivefrmSERVICE, filter);
```

Then send the broadcast from your `service` like this

```
    Intent broadcast = new Intent();
    broadcast.setAction(Global.NOTIFCATION_BROADCAST_ACTION);
    sendBroadcast(broadcast);
```

Then in your `broadcast Receiver` filter this action like this

```
 private BroadcastReceiver ReceivefrmSERVICE = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(Global.NOTIFCATION_BROADCAST_ACTION)) {
                //Do your stuff here :)
            }
    }
   };
```

Comment: Thanks! Ali I get back after trying the same

Comment: **UPDATE**             My Package name is >> "com.winacro.andRHOME." now what I have to write in place of UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_INTENT (should I write intent's name that is intent?)

Comment: you can write any thing inside this variable  `UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_INTENT` because its just a string and used to check the different actions when massages arrive in onReceive() method.Actually it is some sort of unique massage that you want to send to your receiver.

Comment: thanks! but how it checks different actions when messages arrive in onReceive() does it compares something?

Comment: yes i compare what you have send in your sendBroadCast() method like this `broadcast.setAction(Global.NOTIFCATION_BROADCAST_ACTION);` as here you send this string `Global.NOTIFCATION_BROADCAST_ACTION` and compared it in your on receive method. easy:)

Comment: Thanks ALi! ,I'm having error on GLOBAL while keeping cursor on it im not getting any suggestion there!

Comment: Global is a class defined by me in my project

Comment: So you mean first then I have to prepare a GLobal named class and put that varible (ublic static String NOTIFCATION_BROADCAST_ACTION) in it to be accessible to all classes? is there another way where i can keep myself from making this class?

Comment: I think it is a good way but you can declare a static variable in your current class and can access it by using class name from any where.

Comment: can you show me the way to make variables global without making a globally accessible class?

Comment: just write this line in your current class `public static String NOTIFCATION_BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.your_packagename.UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_INTENT";`

Comment: This "public static String NOTIFCATION_BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.your_packagename.UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_INTENT";"

Comment: is this giving you some sort of error? if yes what is the error.

Comment: It says NOTIFICATION_BROADCAST_ACTION cannot resolve to a variable, when I use it in the Service!

Comment: access this variable with your class name i which you have defined it. like if your class name is `MainActivity` then access it any where like this `MainActivity.NOTIFCATION_BROADCAST_ACTION`

Comment: I tried and I was able to access the Variable! but still I wasn't able to get into onReceive() of the Broadcaster and get the Toast! working!! I implemented all as you told me, One thing need to be noted here is that the Broadcast receiver is in a activity that is not active but it has to call it because I need to access a function from it! so I also tried moving the part of code that you told me to insert in onCreate() to onStop() also butit didn't work even there

Comment: If you want to receive the broad cast massage after the activity is resumed from background then use `sticky broad cast`. and also don't forget to unregister it in `onDestroy()` of the activity. like this `unregisterReceiver(ReceivefrmSERVICE)`

Comment: Can't I access the Activity function anyways if its onStop()? or is there any other way that can make me access that function from that activity?